# Windows Python 2.7 multiprocessing.Manager.Queue deadlocks on put from child process

Tags: python, python-2.7, queue, multiprocessing, deadlock

I'm trying to get code similar to the following example working correctly:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Manager, Pool
import time
from datetime import datetime

def results_producer(the_work, num_procs):
    results = Manager().Queue()
    ppool = Pool(num_procs)
    multiplier = 3
    #step = len(the_work)/(num_procs*multiplier)
    step = 100
    for i in xrange(0,len(the_work), step):
        batch = the_work[i:i+step]
        ppool.apply_async(do_work1, args=(i,batch,results))#,callback=results.put_nowait)
    return (ppool, results)

def results_consumer(results, total_work, num_procs, pool=None):
    current = 0
    batch_size=10
    total = total_work
    est_remaining = 0
    while current < total_work:
        size = results.qsize()
        est_remaining = total_work - (current + size)
        if current % 1000 == 0:
            print 'Attempting to retrieve item from queue that is empty? %s, with size: %d and remaining work: %d' % (results.empty(), size, est_remaining)
        item = results.get()
        results.task_done()
        current += 1
        if current % batch_size == 0 or total_work - current < batch_size:
            if pool is not None and est_remaining == 0 and size/num_procs > batch_size:
                pool.apply_async(do_work2, args=(current, item, True))
            else:
                do_work2(current,item, False)
            if current % 1000 == 0:
                print 'Queue size: %d and remaining work: %d' % (size, est_remaining)

def do_work1(i, w, results):
    time.sleep(.05)
    if i % 1000 == 0:
       print 'did work %d: from %d to %d' % (i,w[0], w[-1])
    for j in w:
        #create an increasing amount of work on the queue
        results.put_nowait(range(j*2))

def do_work2(index, item, in_parallel):
    time.sleep(1)
    if index % 50 == 0:
        print 'processed result %d with length %d in parallel %s' % (index, len(item), in_parallel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_workers = 2
    start = datetime.now()
    print 'Start: %s' % start
    amount_work = 4000
    the_work = [i for i in xrange(amount_work)]
    ppool, results = results_producer(the_work, num_workers)

    results_consumer(results, len(the_work), num_workers, ppool)

    if ppool is not None:
        ppool.close()
        ppool.join()
    print 'Took: %s time' % (datetime.now() - start)
```

And it deadlocks on the results.put_nowait call from do_work1 even though the queue is empty! Sometimes the code is able to put all the work on the queue but the results.get call from results_consumer blocks since it is apparently empty even though the work has not been consumed yet.

Additionally, I checked the programming guidelines: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html and believe the above code conforms to it. Lastly the problem in this post: [Python multiprocessing.Queue deadlocks on put and get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121622/python-multiprocessing-queue-deadlocks-on-put-and-get) seems very similar and claims to be solved on Windows (I'm running this on Windows 8.1) however the above code doesn't block due to the parent process attempting to join the child process since the logic is similar to the suggested answer. Any suggestions about the cause of the deadlock and how to fix it? Also in general, what is the best way to enable multiple producers to provide results for a consumer to process in python?

Comment: I don't get any deadlocks on put_nowait (how can it deadlock when it doesn't wait?).  This works ok on linux, except that you are only putting 7 items into a queue and then the program hangs on results.get().  On windows I get: ```[Errno 1450] Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service```, so maybe you are trying to put too much into the queue at once?

Comment: @bj0 you're right about not getting deadlocks on the put_nowait in the above code and thanks for pointing out the number of items on the queue. Turns out the code just waited indefinitely since the while loop condition will always be true! I corrected the code and it works even with a lot of items on the queue. So need to revisit the original code this example is based on and figure out why it doesn't work and how to reproduce it here.